# position relative outside of parent div, no scroll but visisble

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

EDIT:

**In essence my problem appears to be the wish to combine `overflow-y:hidden;` with `overflow-x:visisble;`. Which appears to go against the spec. If anyone knows a workaround be sure to let me know :)!**

---

When I try to position a div slightly outside of it's parent div using `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` the parent div gets a scrollbar.

I dont't want a scrollbar. But obviously when I use `overflow: hidden;` the bit of the child div that's outside of the parent get's cut off.

How to make the bit that's outside of the parent visible, without a scrollbar appearing?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention. the outside div requires to have `overflow-y:hidden;`

EDIT ADDED JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/4/

```
<div style="
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:300px;
background-color:green;
overflow-y:hidden;
">
  <div style="
  width:50%;
  margin-left:50%;
  height:50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:visible;
  background-color:red;
  ">

    <div style="
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
     width: 10px;
    right: -5px;
    ">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't you need an **extra level wrapper** to not interact with overflow-y and that outsider ? https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/11/

Answer (score 0):

stick position: relative; on the parent element before setting the child to have "position: absolute;".

Make sure the parent element (or any elements higher in the dom) does not have "overflow: auto;" associated to it

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'overflow:visible' to the styling of parent div, along position:relative. For child div you can write position:absolute and define positions

Check this

```
overflow:visible;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/5/

Comment: You need to apply overflow:visible to both parents

Comment: You need to adjust the margin or width of the second parent to get what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/6/

Comment: I require overflow-y to be hidden for my application on the container div. https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/9/

Comment: I need it to look like it does on https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhxdz9n/5/. However with `overflow-y:hidden;` on the outer most div.

Comment: Then use Jquery. appendTo() function suits your requirement. append the child to top parent.